# Index Out of Range When Splitting String

Tags: python, string, list, indexing, split

I am attempting what seems like a simple operation-- parsing Cisco router outputs using simple string functions (like 'split').  However, I keep getting an error that an index is out of range, and am not seeing why.

Here is what I am starting with, simple "show ip int brief" output:

```
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet0/0         unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/0.50      10.78.1.205     YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/1         10.233.112.17   YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/2         10.233.112.41   YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/3         10.233.112.50   YES NVRAM  up                    up      
Loopback0                  10.233.112.130  YES NVRAM  up                    up      
Tunnel0                    10.233.112.130  YES unset  up                    up      
sdf-a-wan-rt-02#exit
```

And here is the code I am trying to run against it:

```
links = []
lines = output.split('\n')
for item in lines:
    fields = item.split()
    interface = fields[0]
    ipaddress = fields[1]
    linkstate = fields[4]
    prtcstate = fields[5]
    links.append([interface,ipaddress,linkstate,prtcstate])
print links
```

And here is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\dtruman\Documents\PROJECTS\DEVOPS - ITOC CoE\NETWORK    AUTOMATION\parse_output.py", line 32, in <module>
ipaddress = fields[1]
```

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: It looks like the final line of `output`, "sdf-a-wan-rt-02#exit", doesn't contain six space-separated words as you seemed to be expecting.

Comment: Did you look at `fields` to see if it contains what you thought?

Comment: I think you are on to something,  user5459381.  Maybe I should look at parsing this kind of output by field length, rather than trying to split on a character?

Comment: I don't know the exact nature of your input, but it doesn't look like the fields have consistent length, so splitting by characters is probably the easiest way to go. You could consider ignoring the final row (or somehow processing it differently, if the content is useful), or you could ignore rows with len < 6

Comment: That was it, user5459381-- it was getting snagged on the last two lines because they did not have the expected number of fields.  Thanks for the asist, all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have it, but you need to add a sanity check so that you make sure the data you're getting is what you'd expect. I'd do something like this:

```
links = []
lines = output.split('\n')
for item in lines:
    fields = item.split()
    # make sure data is the proper length so you don't go out of bounds
    if len(fields) != 6:
        continue
    interface = fields[0]
    ipaddress = fields[1]
    linkstate = fields[4]
    prtcstate = fields[5]
    links.append([interface,ipaddress,linkstate,prtcstate])
print links
```

There are other ways you could do this, but this is the first one I could think of. This ensures that you have all 6 columns in the table populated for that line before any data is filled in.

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah, that did it-- the last two lines did not have the expected number of fields so my code was getting hung up there.